# Find empty lines automatically

Tags: empty-line

Is there an easy way to find lines with no content in the PDF file?
That is, lines that are empty due to an error on my side (most of the times) in the tex file and not vertical spaces that were automatically added.

My current solution is adding

```
 \usepackage[left]{lineno}\linenumbers
```

to the code and go over the PDF file myself.

Is there a way to ask LaTeX to mark such lines automatically? to mark lines with only a little content?

Thanks

Comment: there are not really any "lines" in an internal pdf structure, just characters placed at certain coordinates so there isn't really any difference between a vertical space and an empty line, it is hard to know what exactly you mean to distinguish these.  What is an example of tex input that you consider to be an empty line rather than a vertical space?

Comment: For instance, it happened that there was a newline command that I was not aware of in some internal command I was using which added an empty line.

The best definition I could think of is something like "a vertical space that could be reduced by deleting a newline command" or exactly what I'm currently using "an empty line as can be seen by using \usepackage[left]{lineno}\linenumbers"

Thanks